# Rounding double to two decimal places using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, format, double, decimalformat

Trying to round a number, 110.99 with a percentage taken off, say 10 to this: 99.90

Currently I am using,

```
public static String GetDiscountedPrice(double OriginalPrice, int PercentDiscount)
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

    double roundedNumber = (OriginalPrice * (PercentDiscount / 100.0));
    roundedNumber = (OriginalPrice - roundedNumber);

    //roundedNumber = Math.round(((roundedNumber * 100.0) / 100.0));
    roundedNumber = Double.valueOf(df.format(roundedNumber));

    String discountedPrice = String.valueOf(roundedNumber);

    return discountedPrice;
}
```

My issue is that I keep getting the value of 99.89.

When I change DecimalFormat to ("##.#") it outputs 99.9. Well, I need 99.90!

How do I go about doing this without hard coding a '0' at the end?

Appreciate it.